# Marcar/Desmarcar Checkbox a partir de um botão

Tags: jquery, html

Gostaria de usar um botão para poder Marcar/Desmarcar checkbox.
Tenho esse botão que chama uma função, vejam:

```
<button 
  class='btn btn-large' 
  type='button' 
  title='Todos' 
  id='todos' 
  onclick='marcardesmarcar();'>
    <i class='icon-large icon-ok'></i>
</button>
```

A função:

```
function marcardesmarcar(){
  $('.marcar').each(
         function(){
           if ($(".marcar").prop( "checked")) 
           $(this).attr("checked", false);
           else $(this).attr("checked", true);               
         }
    );
}
```

Os checks estão dessa forma:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='marcar' name='check[]'/>
```

Esse script até faz certo na primeira vez, mas na segunda ele não faz nada.

Comment: Se não me engano, o atributo `checked` do HTML (que corresponde a `.attr("checked")`) deixa a caixa marcada independente do valor do atributo, só pelo atributo estar declarado. Acho que `<input type="checkbox" checked="false" />` deixa marcado.

Comment: Seria legal se você avaliasse a melhor resposta para dar o accept, (sinal de "resposta aceita", em verde) e depois aplicasse na resposta escolhida, uma vez só. Deve ser a terceira vez que eu entro aqui e o seu "accept" mudou de lugar. Veja mais neste link: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/)

Comment: Avalei como a melhor a resposta do Anderson Pierok, mas agradeço pelo aviso, serei mais prudente em avaliar e somente após selecionar a melhor resposta.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Teste assim:

```
function marcardesmarcar(){
    $(".marcar").each(
        function() {
            if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            } else {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, valeu pela colaboração.

Comment: Acho que isso faria com que cada check alterne, não? Quer dizer, se metade dos checks estiverem marcados e outra metade estiverem desmarcados, vai inverter tudo, ao invés de marcar todos igualmente, ou desmarcar todos de uma vez.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação @bfavaretto.

Comment: Houve alguma alteração no script?

Comment: Sim, o if estava incorreto, observado pelo @bfavaretto e eu o alterei.

Comment: @adventistapr Clique no link "editada" logo abaixo da resposta para ver as edições que foram feitas.

Comment: Valeu pela dica, mas agora estou com um comportamento estranho, se marco todos e logo após desmarco um e volto a marcar todos os checks ficam alternando.

Comment: @adventistapr Se o que você quer é uma função de marcar ou desmarcar todos (e não alternar o estado de cada um), um botão não é a melhor solução de interface. Seria mais claro usar um outro checkbox: se ele está marcado, todos ficam marcados também; se ele é desmarcado, todos são desmarcados. Pois imagine, com o botão, o que acontece quando você marca manualmente **quase** todos os checkboxes e depois clica no botão. O que é pra acontecer? Marcar os que faltam, ou desmarcar todos? E se você só checar um manualmente?

Comment: Está corretíssimo caro bfavoretto, inclusive tomei para mim essa solução indicada, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 13):

O problema é que no `if` você devia testar o `this`, e não uma coleção de elementos:

```
function marcardesmarcar() {
    $('.marcar').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) this.checked = false;
        else this.checked = true;
    });
}
```

Estando a testar `$('.marcar').prop("checked")`dentro do `if`, a partir do momento que um elemento tiver sido mudado esse `if` vai dar `true`. Presumo que você queira testar o elemento que está a ser percorrido/iterado.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/H544C/1/

Comment: Olá Sérgio, obrigado pelo resposta, por favor faço o seguinte teste nesse seu exemplo, clica para marcar todos os checks e depois clica para desmarcar, isso vai funcionar na primeira vez, na segunda já não.

Comment: @adventistapr, corrigi. É isto que pretende?

Comment: É isso mesmo Sergio, muito obrigado pela grande ajuda.

Answer (score 7):

Com javascript puro vc pode pegar o elemento pelo nome e atribuir o valor do checked de `marcar/desmarcar todos` aos demais no onclick(), pois `getElementsByName()` retorna uma array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function marcarTodos(marcar){
        var itens = document.getElementsByName('cores[]');

        if(marcar){
            document.getElementById('acao').innerHTML = 'Desmarcar Todos';
        }else{
            document.getElementById('acao').innerHTML = 'Marcar Todos';
        }

        var i = 0;
        for(i=0; i<itens.length;i++){
            itens[i].checked = marcar;
        }

    }
</script>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cores[]" onclick="marcarTodos(this.checked);">
     <span id="acao">Marcar</span> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cores[]" value="azul"> azul <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cores[]" value="verde"> verde <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cores[]" value="branco"> branco <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#MarcarTodos").click(function(){
        if ($(this).prop( "checked")){ 
            marcardesmarcar(true);
        }else{
            marcardesmarcar(false);
        }
    });

    function marcardesmarcar(bool){
      $('.marcar').each(
            function(){
               $(this).prop("checked", bool);            
             }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Criei o mesmo script de uma maneira mais simples:

```html
marcarTodosCheckBoxes: function (seletorCheckBoxes) {
        $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop('checked'));
        $(seletorCheckBoxes).prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite!

Estou montando uma biblioteca de eventos `Jquery` para ser utilizada em qualquer projeto, e consegui criar esse mesmo script dessa forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#ckAll").click(function()  {  // minha chk que marcará as outras

if ($("#ckAll").prop("checked"))   // se ela estiver marcada... 

$(".chk").prop("checked", true);  // as que estiverem nessa classe ".chk" tambem serão marcadas
     else $(".chk").prop("checked", false);   // se não, elas tambem serão desmarcadas

   });
});
```

funciona perfeitamente, e acredito que ele esteja de forma simples e objetiva!
aprimorada na base dos exemplos acima...

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function marcarTodos(marcardesmarcar){
        $('.marcar').each(function () {
            this.checked = marcardesmarcar;
        });
    }
</script>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cores[]" onclick="marcarTodos(this.checked);">
     <span id="acao">Marcar</span> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="marcar" name="cores[]" value="azul"> azul <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="marcar" name="cores[]" value="verde"> verde <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="marcar" name="cores[]" value="branco"> branco <br>
</form>
```