# Função em javascript para desmarcar/limpar todas as checkboxes selecionadas a partir de um botão

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Tenho várias checkboxes num formulário, que serão marcadas pelo usuário. Caso o mesmo deseje, poderá limpar todas ao clicar num botão, conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: checkboxes]

tentei utilizar esta função em javascript:

```
function myFunctionClear() {
  for (i = 0; i < document.selecao.elements.length; i++)
    if (document.selecao.elements[i].type == "checkbox")
      document.selecao.elements[i].checked = 0
}
```

no meu botão

```
<button class='btn  custom' onclick="myFunctionClear()">Limpar Seleção</button>
```

mas por algum motivo não está funcionando. a outra resposta do StackOverflow que encontrei ([Marcar/Desmarcar Checkbox a partir de um botão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17713/marcar-desmarcar-checkbox-a-partir-de-um-bot%C3%A3o)) mostra um botão que marca e demarca todas as checkboxes, porém só desejo a opção de desmarcar. 
link para o jsfidlle: https://jsfiddle.net/elenderg/tdvqp4xL/

Comment: [Marcar/Desmarcar Checkbox a partir de um botão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17713/91)

Comment: Imagino que todos os checkboxs tem o mesmo nome, pode pegar eles e dar `checked=false` em todos ou pegar pela tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve remover o atributo `checked`

```
function myFunctionClear() {
  for (i = 0; i < document.selecao.elements.length; i++)
    if (document.f1.elements[i].type == "checkbox")
      document.f1.elements[i].removeAttribute("checked");
}
```

Ou marcá-lo como `false`

```
function myFunctionClear() {
  for (i = 0; i < document.selecao.elements.length; i++)
    if (document.f1.elements[i].type == "checkbox")
      document.f1.elements[i].checked = false;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Eu assumi que `document.f1` representasse a tag `<form>` que possui os checkboxes a serem desmarcados. O código abaixo é baseado no exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/elenderg/tdvqp4xL/

Primeiro: Substitua o formulário que você inseriu dentro de outro formulário

```
    <form action="form_action.asp">
      <form name="selecao">
```

por:

```
    <form action="form_action.asp" name="selecao">
```

Segundo: Reescreva a função `myFunctionClear`

```
function myFunctionClear() {
  for (i = 0; i < document.forms.selecao.elements.length; i++)
    if (document.forms.selecao.elements[i].type == "checkbox")
      document.forms.selecao.elements[i].checked = false;
}
```

Comment: tentei e não funcionou....

Comment: agora sim, desculpe por ter postado o código errado...

Answer (score 1):

Existe um jeito mais simples, e mais performático de fazer isso sem utilizar um for para desmarcar esses campos selecionados. Da uma olhada:

```
function myFunctionClear() {
  var inputs = $('input[type=checkbox]');

  inputs.attr('checked', false);
  inputs.prop('checked', false);
}
```

Comment: Essa solução funciona mas acho que é expansiva demais uma vez que captura todos os checkboxes da página. A linha `inputs.prop('checked', false);` não produz efeito nesse contexto e poderia ser removida.

Comment: Entendo seu ponto, e você realmente está certo. Mas já utilizei essa solução em uma aplicação que atendia perfeitamente o requisito... Ai acho que vai mais da necessidade mesmo.
A linha inputs.prop('checked', false); eu adicionei só como garantia, acredito que se a função for chamada duas vezes, a segunda não se comportaria como o esperado sem essa linha, mas vale o teste :)