# Marcando uma checkbox como selecionada

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho uma lista de filtros com `checkbox` em uma página e queria que uma dessas seleções fosse marcada como ativa ao clicar em um banner que estará dentro dessa página.

Exemplo:

```
<img src="fakeurl.com" alt="Teste">  <label class="sr_teste" title="Teste" 
 index="0" style="display: flex;"><input rel="fq=specificationFilter_x:Teste" 
 class="multi-search-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Teste" 
 value="Teste">Teste</label>
```

Há alguma maneira de fazer essa `checkbox` ficar selecionada ao clicar na imagem ?

Comment: você pode usar uma função jquery/javascript... Acredito que sua duvida seja a mesma desse link. A diferença que você vai chamar no onclick do banner. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17713/marcar-desmarcar-checkbox-a-partir-de-um-bot%C3%A3o Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer coisa, pode chamar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa criar uma coleção das imagens (que você chama de "banner") colocando uma classe nelas (ex. `class="banners"`):

```
<img class="banners" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="Teste">
```

Então você cria eventos onclick em cada imagem com a classe:

```
const banners = document.querySelectorAll(".banners");
for(let banner of banners){
   banner.onclick = function(){
      let alt = this.alt;
      let box = document.querySelector("[type='checkbox'][value='"+alt+"']");
      box.checked = !box.checked;
   }
}
```

É preciso vincular uma imagem a um checkbox. No caso acima eu usei o atributo `alt` da imagem com o atributo `value` do checkbox, já que o `value` deve ser único, ou seja, o `alt` da imagem deve ser exatamente o mesmo do `value` do checkbox vinculado.

A linha `box.checked = !box.checked;` irá marcar/desmarcar o checkbox a cada clique na imagem.

Exemplo:

```js
const banners = document.querySelectorAll(".banners");
for(let banner of banners){
   banner.onclick = function(){
      let alt = this.alt;
      let box = document.querySelector("[type='checkbox'][value='"+alt+"']");
      box.checked = !box.checked;
   }
}
```

```css
.banners{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img class="banners" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="Teste">  <label class="sr_teste" title="Teste" index="0" style="display: flex;"><input rel="fq=specificationFilter_x:Teste" class="multi-search-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Teste" value="Teste">Teste</label>
```